# Android Emulator - Cannot get keyboard to display

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-2.3-gingerbread, android-keypad

Basically I cannot get the onscreen keyboard to display at all.

I've tried every solution I've read to make it appear within my application, and now I've come to the conclusion that it must be the emulator as it isn't appearing when using Messages, writing e-mails etc.

I've looked in Language & input within settings and checked Sample Soft Keyboard, rebooted the emulator with no change.

Using Android SKD 2.3.3

3.7in WVGA (Nexus One)

I'm hoping someone can maybe guess what's going on.

Many thanks

Comment: have you tried cleaning your project? restarting eclipse? deleting and re-creating your AVD?

Comment: Yeah I tried all that, no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this to get soft keyboard on `device`:

```
edit_Text.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    if(hasFocus){
        ((InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE))
.showSoftInput(edit_Text, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
    }else
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "lost the focus", 2000).show();
}
});
```

For `emulator`,I think that it is not guaranteed.Really I did not any way to appear soft keyboard programmatically.Some times it appears and some times not.In emulator with android 4.0.3,you can see a symbol in notification bar instead of appearing soft keyboard:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help, yeah the little keyboard icon at the top is always present. Doesn't matter which option I click, I've still never seen the keyboard. I'll mark your reply as the answer, as typically this would be, time to focus on something else :)